# Eslint with VSCode Align Package

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm trying to align my variables using the align package for VSCode so they match up nicely like so:

```
const fs        = require('fs')
const something = require('http')
```

But every time I format or beautify... it returns to a single space before the equal sign.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const something = require('http')
```

Is there a setting I can change in my `.estlintrc` file to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this ESLint issue](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/1524) you could do the following inside your `.eslintrc`:

```
"no-multi-spaces": [1, {
    "exceptions": {
        "VariableDeclarator": true
    }
}]
```

Comment: awesome! Thanks heaps :)